# Open file.html from within script.php

Tags: php, redirect

I want to call a php script from an Anchor.

file.html

```
<body>
    <a href="file.php?id=1">Click</a>
</body>
```

script.php

```
<?php

    $id = $_GET['id'];

    ... <do some stuff>;

    <when finished doing some stuff reload file.html>;

?>
```

Then once my php in script.php has run I want to reopen the original file.  I've tried load() and loadHTML(), neither has worked.  What PHP function will load file.html?

Thanks so much.

Comment: @Marc B - If you use an include, you'll just be injecting HTML straight into the PHP code, generating plenty of syntax errors.

Comment: @derek: nope. unless the included file starts with a `<?php`, it'll be treated as plaintext and output as such. There is no such thing as a "php script". there is only "text files which happen to contain php blocks".

Comment: @Narc B - Oh, that's right. I've been spending way too much time in C and C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to redirect the user to the original page:

```
header( 'Location: http://example.com/file.html' );
```

Just make sure you don't output anything (send data to the browser) before redirecting.

Comment: Depending of a case, it might be useful to add `die();` or `exit;` immediately after the `header('Location: ...');`, in order to ensure suspending the execution of the script.

Comment: @Rolice - Very true. Doesn't matter in this case since the redirect appears to be at the end of the script, but if there were more code afterward (such as redirecting based on a condition), you would definitely want to add `die()` or `exit()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo file_get_contents("file.html");
```